# How to redirect to a url in laravel without adding base url to it?

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel using route('/index',[],false), by setting third parameter to url we get relative path. But when I use Redirect::intended('/dashboard') then how to get relative path. Now it is adding /dashboard to BASE_URL

Answer (score 0):

```
Redirects
// Redirect to url
redirect('itsolution');
// Redirect to url with data
redirect('itsolution')->with('key', 'value');
// Redirect to url with input data
redirect('itsolution')->withInput(Input::get());
// Redirect to url with error
redirect('itsolution')->withErrors($validator);
// Redirect to back url
back()->withInput();

// Redirect to route url 
redirect()->route('login');
// For a route with the following URI: view/{id}
redirect()->route('view', ['id' => 1]);
// For a route with the following URI: view/{id}/edit/{id_sub}
redirect()->route('profile', [$user]);

// Redirect to controller method
redirect()->action('HomeController@index');
// Redirect to controller method with argument
redirect()->action('UserController@profile', ['id' => 1]);
// Response macro
response()->caps('foo');
// Redirect intend url
redirect()->intended('dashboard');
// Redirect back url
redirect()->back();
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Code only answers are improved by some explanation as to how they answer the question.